# Tabular record display with XSLT i.e. Records display x columns, then new row

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
 <record>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>David</name>
  <age>40</age> 
 </record>
 <record>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>Tully</name>
  <age>38</age>
 </record>
 <record>
  <id>3</id> 
  <name>Solai</name>
  <age>32</age>
 </record>
 <record>
  <id>4</id> 
  <name>Michael</name>
  <age>49</age>
 </record>
 <record>
  <id>5</id> 
  <name>Tony</name>
  <age>19</age>
 </record>
 <record>
  <id>6</id> 
  <name>Ray</name>
  <age>26</age>
 </record>
 <record>
  <id>7</id> 
  <name>Leeha</name>
  <age>13</age>
 </record>

</data>
```

I want to display the records as similar to a dataview in asp.net, like the following:

```
record 1   record2   record3   record4
record 5   record6   record7   record8
```

and so on.

I have the following XSL at the moment which is shakey to say the least!

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

 <div>
 <table style="width: 200px" border="1">

  <tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="data/record">

   <xsl:if test="position() mod 4 = 0">
   <tr></tr>
   </xsl:if> 

   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="name"></xsl:value-of>
    <br />
    <xsl:value-of select="age"></xsl:value-of>
   </td>

  </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>

 </table>
 </div>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So my question is, am I on the correct path here.. or is there a more simple, robust way to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this a while ago (I've just adapted it to suit your XML schema):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

   <xsl:output method="html"/> 

   <xsl:variable name="M" select="5"/> 
   <xsl:variable name="C" select="2"/> 

   <xsl:template match="/"> 
      <html> 
        <body> 
           <table border="1"> 
             <xsl:for-each select="/data/record[position() mod ($M * $C) = 1]"> 
                <tr>
                  <xsl:for-each select=".|following-sibling::record[position() mod $M = 0 and position() &lt; $M * $C]">
                    <td>
                      <xsl:for-each select=".|following-sibling::record[position() &lt; $M]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/><br/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </td>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                  <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                    <xsl:call-template name="empty-cells">
                      <xsl:with-param name="nb" select="$C - ceiling(count(.|following-sibling::record) div $M)"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                  </xsl:if>
                </tr>
             </xsl:for-each> 
           </table> 
        </body> 
      </html> 
   </xsl:template> 

   <xsl:template name="empty-cells">
    <xsl:param name="nb"/>
    <xsl:if test="$nb &gt;= 1">
        <td/>
        <xsl:call-template name="empty-cells">
          <xsl:with-param name="nb" select="$nb - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>       
   </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Variable C is the number of columns, and variable M is the number of records per cell.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [How can I break a table row in xsl after a specified count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377377/how-can-i-break-a-table-row-in-xsl-after-a-specified-count)

Or also this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <div>
      <table style="width: 200px" border="1">

        <tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="data/record">
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="name" /><br />
              <xsl:value-of select="age" />
            </td>
            <xsl:if test="position() mod 4 = 0 and position() != last()">
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                 &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;
              </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The second answer is simple and effective - there is a "gotcha" though, you need to catch for the case where the last row has exactly four items and *not* drop the extra break in.

Comment: @Murph: I can't test it right now but a `and position != last()` should do the trick; I edited my answer to reflect this, ty

Comment: @Rubens: I agree (I resisted the temptation to exercise my shiny new "edit" rights to make exactly the same change - not quite worked out the ettiquette of that yet!)

Comment: Hi guys! thanks so much for all the examples.. really very useful.  I like the simplicity of this answer, although I can see why the other answers (from Erlock below and the one above) have more flexibility perhaps.. but either way, really many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
  <xsl:template match="/data">
    <div>
       <table style="width: 200px" border="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="record[position() mod 4 = 1]"/>
      </table>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="record">
    <row>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::record[position() &lt; 4]" mode="mode" />
    </row>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="record" mode="mode">
    <cell>
      <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
    </cell>
    <xsl:if test="position() = last() and position() &lt; 3">
      <xsl:call-template name="complete-row">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="position()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="complete-row">
     <xsl:param name="count"/>
     <td>&#160;</td>
     <xsl:if test="($count + 1) &lt; 3">
        <xsl:call-template name="complete-row">
           <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: forgot to change 'mode' name from default to something more sensible

Comment: @Rubens Farias: hacking node-tree output with xsl:text disable-output-escaping is no good.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are roughly on the right lines, but you have an empty `tr` embedded in another `tr` which isn't going to do anything useful and may foul up browsers. If you post the HTML you expect then it will be clearer how to achieve it.