# How can I group homogenous data in xsl?

Tags: xslt

Let's say we have following data:

```
<all>
    <item id="1"/>
    <item id="2"/>
    ...
    <item id="N"/>
</all>
```

What is the most elegant, xslt-ish way to group those items?
For example, imagine we want a table with two cells in each row.
Off the top of my head I can imagine (not tested though)
in template, matching item, I can call this very item, selecting following-sibling.
But even in this case I should pass additional param, to make recursion finite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I break a table row in xsl after a specified count?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377377/how-can-i-break-a-table-row-in-xsl-after-a-specified-count)

Answer (score 0):

As row-count can be variable .. am passing it as a param to the template .. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/all[node]">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="node[1]">
        <xsl:call-template name="whoaa">
          <xsl:with-param name="count" select="'1'"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="row_count" select="'10'"/>
          <!--maximum row_count is set to 10 -->
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="whoaa">
    <xsl:param name="count"/>
    <xsl:param name="row_count"/>
    <!--check if we have crossed row_count-->
    <xsl:if test="not ($row_count &lt; $count)">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <!--copy next column-->
          <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::node[1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!--Select next row .. call the same template untill we reach (row_count > count)-->
      <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::node[2]">
        <xsl:call-template name="whoaa">
          <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count+2"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="row_count" select="$row_count"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: assumed your sample XML as it is. If the structure of input XML changes then its `<template match=""/>` would also change.

Answer (score 0):

use position and mod, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/all">
    <table>
    <xsl:apply-templates name="item" mode="group"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[position() mod 2=1]" mode="group">
<tr>
<td><xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="render"/></td>
<td><xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item[1]" mode="render"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[position() mod 2=0]"></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="render">item: <xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:template>
```